# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called on uiWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have put a web view inside a uitableviewcell

Problem :

didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called while tap or touch on uiwebview

Any idea how to overcome this problem ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`.